# 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple

Tags: python

I was trying to make a function that checks if a  string contains words but I keep on running to this error `'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple`Im fairly new to python so I'm not sure why it's not working. any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
def syntaxCheck(s):
    words = ("for", "if", "else", "elif", "while", "def", "not") 
    if words in s:
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")
syntaxCheck("if while else")
```

Comment: As the error message tells you, the left-hand operand (`words` in your code) must be a string, not a tuple. You will have to use a loop to check for each word rather than trying to check for all of them in one go. There are helpers that implement the loop internally and could do the job. As an example: `any(x in s for x in words)` will return `True` if any of the words are in the string.

Comment: @deadshot they want to check if any of those words are in the string, not if the string is in the list of words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use a loop to check for each word rather than trying to check for all of them in one go.

Rather than implementing the loop yourself, there are helpers that implement the loop internally and could do the job. As an example: `any(x in s for x in words)` will return `True` if any of the words are in the string. You could use it like this:

```
def syntaxCheck(s):
    words = ("for", "if", "else", "elif", "while", "def", "not") 
    if any(x in s for x in words):
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")

syntaxCheck("if while else")
```

Note that the two uses of `in` are different syntactically. The first (`x in s`) is the check to see if the string `x` is in the string `s`. The second (`for x in words`) iterates over the words in `words`, assigning each to the variable `x` to use in the first half.

Alternatively, if you need to check that the string *only* contains the words you're interested in, you can use `all` instead of `any`:

```
def syntaxCheck(s):
    words = ("for", "if", "else", "elif", "while", "def", "not") 
    if all(x in words for x in s.split()):
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")

syntaxCheck("if while else")
```

You should familiarise yourself with the [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) as you'll find them very useful.

Comment: but that will still print true if s contains other words. Ex: syntaxCheck("if hello while"). prints true. @Kemp

Comment: You didn't make that requirement clear in your question. You said "if a string contains words", not "if a string contains only these words". I'll make an edit to give you what you need.

Comment: that wont work that check if all words are in s.@Kemp

Comment: Oops, my mistake. I've fixed that. Typed a bit too quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to convert the string to a list of words using `s_list = s.split()` and after iterating the list and comparing each value like this:

```python
flag = False
for i in s_list:
    if i in words:
        flag = True
```